# If a bat kohen marries an Israelite am haaretz do the usual laws of Chattan/kallah not apply

Tags: halacha, kohen-priest, wedding, sheva-brachos, even-haezer

The Talmud in Masechet [Pesachim 49a](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.49a.12) states that a bat kohen marriage to an  Israelite am Haaretz is not a Seudat mitzvah. My question is, are there any other areas of Halacha where this situation is different, such as the restriction on melacha for a week (or 3 days), simchat Chattan v’kallah, and Sheva berachot?

Comment: "_The Talmud in Masechet Pesachim 49a states that a bat kohen marriage to an Israelite am Haaretz is not a Seudat mitzvah._" That's inaccurate. It actually says a Seudah is not a Seudat Mitzvah "in a case [where] the daughter of a priest (_bat Kohen_) [is married] to an Israelite (_le-yisrael_), or [where] the daughter of a Torah scholar (_bat talmid chakham_) [is married] to an ignoramus (_le-am ha-aretz_)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems from the commentators that it's only referring to the aspect of Seudas Mitzva, since the union is deemed a slight to the Cohanic dynasty by sullying it with an ignoramus. There's no Mitzva in participating in such a party.

Rashi for example (רש"י על פסחים מ״ט א:י״ב:ב׳) says **אין זווגן עולה יפה - במזל טוב - it's going to be an unfortunate union.** He does not say it's an invalid or incomplete union or that any wedding-related Halacha is suspended.

Note: The Meiri mentions that a wedding between 2 ignoramus non-Cohanic families would be a Seudas Mitzva.

Comment: "... _since the union is deemed a slight to the Cohanic dynasty by sullying it with an ignoramus._" Should that be "...since the union is deemed a slight to the Cohanic dynasty by sullying it with an **Israelite**", as the text says "בת כהן ל**ישראל**"?